# Mocha integration "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

In my project i have describe unit and integration testing. Unit working fine but while time for testing of integration, it generates error i.e, `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Error Screenshot:-

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This error is generally in case where you call a function recursively and do not specify a base case to stop recursion. Looking at your code will help find the problem.